# pentaho excel java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: excel, pentaho, kettle, pdi

When I try to get excel sheets with Excel Input, Pentaho Data Integration gives the following error:

```
2016/05/25 18:37:38 - Entrada Excel 2.0 - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : Error processing row from Excel file [C:\Users\Dante\Desktop\pdi\temp\valores cuota\valores_cuota_20160525_171541.xls] : java.lang.NullPointerException
2016/05/25 18:37:38 - Entrada Excel 2.0 - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : java.lang.NullPointerException
2016/05/25 18:37:38 - Entrada Excel 2.0 -   at jxl.read.biff.SheetReader.handleOutOfBoundsCells(SheetReader.java:1900)
2016/05/25 18:37:38 - Entrada Excel 2.0 -   at jxl.read.biff.SheetReader.read(SheetReader.java:1177)
2016/05/25 18:37:38 - Entrada Excel 2.0 -   at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.readSheet(SheetImpl.java:716)
2016/05/25 18:37:38 - Entrada Excel 2.0 -   at jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser.getSheet(WorkbookParser.java:257)
2016/05/25 18:37:38 - Entrada Excel 2.0 -   at jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser.getSheet(WorkbookParser.java:290)
2016/05/25 18:37:38 - Entrada Excel 2.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.jxl.XLSWorkbook.getSheet(XLSWorkbook.java:78)
2016/05/25 18:37:38 - Entrada Excel 2.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.getRowFromWorkbooks(ExcelInput.java:580)
2016/05/25 18:37:38 - Entrada Excel 2.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.processRow(ExcelInput.java:430)
2016/05/25 18:37:38 - Entrada Excel 2.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2016/05/25 18:37:38 - Entrada Excel 2.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I downloaded the excel from the following URL:
http://www.svs.cl/institucional/estadisticas/fm.fm_bpr_dia.php?admins=0&tipofondo=0&moneda=0&dia_select=17&mes_peri=05&anio_peri=2016&out=excel&lang=es

If I open the file with Microsoft Excel and save the error does not appear

You can download the example from https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByUqPOuRQxfbS3ZpdlRBS3N0SGs

Comment: Don't post your code separately, paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that "Microsoft Excel Step" expects excel file to be in certain form. More precisely, it expects excel sheet to have first row the header, which u can omit in "Content" tab, then following data rows.

Your excel have first 9 rows of some data, just heading not actual data for processing. Unfortunately there is no way to omit first 9 row in step configuration dialog.

Well, if it is really necessary work to be done using kettle,  when u can use "User Defined Java Step" to write custom data loader from excel with apache-poi (https://poi.apache.org/)

It is already in classpath in PDI Kettle in directory called "lib/".